# Ingress rule can't connect to ingress nginx controller admission webhook

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks

Upon creating an ingress rule for my argo cd installation, I get an error below

```
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": EOF
```

My ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-http-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: argocd.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argocd-server
                port:
                  name: http
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - argocd.example.com
      secretName: argocd-secret
```

I confirmed my nginx resources are running. I have nginx setup to use a private IP (private link service in azure) in my vnet.

```
 ~  kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.74.44    172.19.0.8    80:31645/TCP,443:32194/TCP   4d8h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.54.183   <none>        443/TCP                      4d8h
```

The part I don't understand is I initially recreated the cluster and it was fine. I then changed the `host` section of my ingress rule and that's when it broke. For example, like changing `argocd-prod.example.com` to what's shown in the example ingress rule, `argocd.example.com`. I'm still learning kubernetes so I don't fully understand the implications of what I did but it seems that there might be some kind of cached data somewhere? Because I see this error in the nginx pod logs

```
local SSL certificate argocd/argocd-secret was not found
```

Answer (score 1):

When facing issues with an Ingress rule in Kubernetes, particularly when encountering webhook failures like `failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io"`, there are several steps you can take to diagnose and resolve the problem:

Verify that the `ingress-nginx-controller-admission` service is operational. Use `kubectl get svc`
[image]

and `kubectl get endpoints` in your namespace.
[image]

Confirm the existence and correctness of the `argocd-secret` TLS secret in the `argocd` namespace `kubectl get secret argocd-secret -n argocd`.

[image]

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=argocd
```

[image]

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]
For scenarios where a load balancing service isn't in use, you can establish an Ingress rule similar to the following example. It's crucial to include the `ssl-passthrough` annotation, as Argo CD utilizes various protocols, including gRPC and HTTPS, concurrently on a single port, specifically port 443. This annotation ensures proper handling of these mixed protocols.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: argocd-server
          servicePort: https
```

Ensure annotations in your Ingress rule are correctly configured. If using SSL passthrough (`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"`), the nginx ingress controller needs the `--enable-ssl-passthrough` flag.

- If you've changed the hostname (e.g., from `argocd-prod.example.com` to `argocd.example.com`), ensure the DNS is correctly updated to point to your ingress controller's external IP.
  Lastly if all these are not helping, you can try restarting the nginx ingress controller
  `kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment-name> -n ingress-nginx`.

Reference Documents:
[ArgoCD](https://devops.cisel.ch/deploy-argocd-and-a-first-app-on-kubernetes)
[GitHub ArgoCD](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/discussions/11052)
[Official ArgoCD doc for configuring ingress](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/operator-manual/ingress/)